# cqlsh no viable alternative at input ':'

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

hello I need to execute this commande properly, remotly from jenkins

```
ssh -T -i /home/jenkins-brs/.ssh/id_rsa cassandra@myhost 'sh /var/cassandra/bin/cqlsh -e "ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 2, 'DC2' : 2};"'
```

But i have this error:

```
<stdin>:1:SyntaxException: line 1:47 no viable alternative at input ':' (... system_auth WITH REPLICATION = {[class] :...)
```

This is what i expect on cassandra table:

```
system_auth | True | {'DC1': '2', 'DC2': '2', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error doesn't match what you pasted as your command. It looks from error like you have `class` instead of `'class'`.

[with update] The ssh uses single quote for your shell command which looks like causes are some escaping issues ending the query after the `WITH REPLICATION = {`. If you use double quotes instead you can escape the ones in cqlsh arg with a backslash.

Comment: Hi i made some change on my question... its a problem caused by ' ' inside ' '

Comment: Finally i used : ssh -T -i /home/jenkins-brs/.ssh/id_rsa cassandra@myhost 'sh /var/cassandra/bin/cqlsh -f command.cql'